How do I repeat an image on both sides vertically?
I've only successfully made the background image go down vertically on the left side of the website. But I haven't figured out how to make the background image do the same thing to the right of the webpage.
<style>
    body {
    background-image: url('background.png');
    background-size: 950px;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;

    }
</style>

I've tried duplicating the image and making it go to the right but that didn't work. It just ended up messing with the background image to the left go to the center.

If you only want your image repeat vertically but on both sides of your page. You may give 2 same backgrounds but put them on different sides:
background:
  url('background.png') left / 950px repeat-y, 
  url('background.png') right / 950px repeat-y;

Pay attention it's background but not background-image. It is a shorthand for:
background-image: url('background.png'), url('background.png');
background-position-x: left, right;
background-size: 950px, 950px;
background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat-y;

Here's a live example:


body {
  background: 
    url('https://picsum.photos/120/120') left / 120px repeat-y, 
    url('https://picsum.photos/120/120') right / 120px repeat-y;
}




Background is a shorthand property for background-image, if you look at the formal syntax in the link you provided,  background:
url('https://picsum.photos/120/120') is same as  background-image:
url('https://picsum.photos/120/120')

@Symtox Yes, and no. background is a set of attributes you can assign not only background-image but also other attributes (background-position-x, background-size, etc.) as well, using background-image here will break the code. It's easier to assosiate each attribute related to one background-image using this shorthand when you have multiple backgrounds provided IMO.

You can use multiple background images in CSS. This involves specifying the same image twice, once for the left side and once for the right side, and positioning them accordingly.
One instance of the background image on the left side and another on the right side of the webpage, both repeating vertically. You can adjust the background-size and background-position values as your requirement.


body {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300'), url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');
  background-size: 100px auto, 100px auto;
  background-position: left top, right top;
  background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat-y;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Background Image on Both Sides</title>      
    </head>
    <body>        
       <!-- Your content here -->
    </body>
</html>



